# Proving Equations (Complex Conjugates)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> > The question is: $z$ is a complex number given by $z$ $=$ $sin$$(\theta)$ $+$ $i(1-cos(\theta))$, $-\pi < \theta < \pi $ Show that if $w$ $=$ $\frac 1{z-i}$ then $w$ $=$ $z^* + i $ where $z^*$ is the conjugate of z.

---

What I have attempted

by letting $$ z = sin(\theta) + i(1-cos(\theta)) $$

Expanding gives us

$$ z = sin(\theta) + i-icos(\theta) $$

Inputting this into the first $w$ equation

$$w = \frac 1{z-i}$$

$$w = \frac 1{sin(\theta) + i-icos(\theta)-i}$$

$$ w = \frac 1{sin(\theta) -icos(\theta)}$$

Now using the second equation

$$w = z^* + i $$

and (this is the part where I am unsure by using $z$ $=$ $sin$$(\theta)$ $+$ $i(1-cos(\theta))$  , is the conjugate just replacing the $+$ sign with a $-$  sign or replacing $\theta$ with $-\theta$) , I'm going to go with replacing the signs.

so  $$z^* = sin(\theta) - i(1-cos(\theta))    $$

Inputting it into the second equation

$$w = z^* + i $$

$$w = sin(\theta) - i(1-cos(\theta))  + i $$

$$ w = sin(\theta) + cos(\theta)) $$

However the first equation does not equal the second , did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z-i=\sin\theta-i\cos\theta$$

$$z^*+i=\sin\theta-i(1-\cos\theta)+i=\sin\theta+i\cos\theta$$

$$\implies(z-i)(z^*+i)=\cdots=1$$